# Registry Key required to access twice to get value?

Tags: c#, console, registry

Im confused on this one and its hard for me to explain but lets try this..

I run a few installation programs serially then launch a seperate process to run a configuration program.

the installations are run clean and simple via console, on exe's and msi files.

```
start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                        start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                        start.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        start.Arguments = s.args;
                        start.FileName = tempDir + "/" + s.executable;
                        start.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        Process.Start(start).WaitForExit();
```

The configuration program sets a few registry values and reads a few that were set by the installations. The program I am running into is that I have to run the configuration twice in order to read teh values...

```
if (winVer == 32)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Enter 32 bit");
                RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\KEY\Settings");
                workingDir = key.GetValue("WorkingDir").ToString();
                //Console.WriteLine(key);
                key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\KEY");
                installPath = key.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString();
                //Console.WriteLine(key);
                key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\KEY\Runtime\
                sdkPath = key.GetValue("Path").ToString();
                //Console.WriteLine(key);
            }
```

**the first time this function executes it returns null values for all the registry keys (there is valid error handling just not sited)
however if I imediatly exit the console application and respawn it the above keys all read flawlessly.**

Is there some kind of delay on reading the registry from insallation of a key to when it can be read. or is there some kind of refresh on the registry i should force before reading after the insalls?

any information on **how to over come this but more importantly why this occurs** would be beneficial

**It apears that the registry keys do not exist within the registry until first launch of the program in Windows 7, 
My program tries to grab the keys then launch the final program however I need to switch this around.**

which brings me to launching the program... I am launching the process with

```
        ProcessStartInfo start = null;

        start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        start.CreateNoWindow = true;
        start.FileName = proc;

        Process.Start(start).WaitForInputIdle();
```

this however creates more issues as the process is 2step it loads the main program then loads the file into it  (this code works for that) but causes the issue that the main programe enters the *inputIdle* loop before the file is loaded into the program, causing the whole applicaation to continue putting me back to *no registry keys found*

Comment: Where is the code used to create the keys?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey it really is just a standard "launch exe" style the keys are added from installers  `start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                            start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                            start.CreateNoWindow = true;
                            start.Arguments = s.args;
                            start.FileName = tempDir + "/" + s.executable;
                            start.CreateNoWindow = true;
                            Process.Start(start).WaitForExit();`

Comment: Your description sounds like a textbook race condition.  The confusing part for me is how a race condition occurs if this is a serial process and you did in fact call `WaitForExit()`.  Are you certain the configuration program runs *after* the installation program?

Comment: yes... see the installation is run in 1 program using the waitForexit. after that completes it initializes an extraction program that unzips a few compressed files (unrelated to the install but used int he config program) then at this point it launches the configuration program that attempts to retrieve the registry keys... It sounds so much like a race condition but there is a good 1-2 minutes between the installations and the read. 


additionally i should mention that this is specifically on windows 7(32bit), on xp and vista the program works as intended.

Comment: Do you happen to be installing from an external USB device like a thumb drive?

Comment: I've seen a similar situation in the past. It happened when the first process ran as a normal user and the second as an elevated Admin user (in UAC mode). With you saying it works in XP but not Win7, this sounds like it could be UAC. Installers sometimes raise UAC halfway through an install. Might be worth checking this by running the app as an administrator.

Comment: Can you manually see the keys before running the configuration program ?

Comment: @c4store I will check that

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey no its all internal

Comment: @SimonGoldstron interesting, I am logged in as admin during the time, but it could be part of the issue with the way win 7 works with security I will run from the begining as admin and check.